# Data not passing between Controllers

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

Hi I am trying to pass data from one Controller to another but the data is not displaying on the other end of UI .

***this is my service code :-***

```
app.factory('ServiceF', function($rootScope) {

 var service = {};
  service.data = false;
  service.sendData = function(data){
      this.data = data;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('data_shared');
  };
  service.getData = function(){
    return this.data;
  };
  return service;
});
```

***Controller 1 Code :-***

```
app.controller('Ctrlone', ["$scope", "ServiceF", function ($scope, ServiceF) {

$scope.Info= {};
        $scope.ser= function(){
          ServiceF.sendData($scope.Info);
           console.log($scope.Info);
           };
    }]);
```

*The  `$scope.Info` data is coming successfully here from other source which I haven't posted . But it is coming.*

***Controller 2 :-***

```
app.controller('Ctrltwo', ["$scope" ,"ServiceF",
function($scope , ServiceF) {
$scope.Info= '';
                $scope.$on('data_shared',function(){
                   var good = ServiceF.getData();    
             $scope.Info = good;
        });
}]);
```

***UI where I want to display info :-***

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
            <h1 class="mainTitle">Ok Start </h1>
            <h2>{{good}}</h2>

</div>
```

*Button click function from 1st UI :-*

```
<label class="cardlabel" style="width:11vw" ui-sref="uitwo" ng-click="ser()">Send</label>
```

Now where am I going wrong ? Info is not displaying on 2nd UI. And how can I check if data is passing on Service ?

Comment: It would be much easier to find(and avoid) bugs in your code if you indented it properly and in a consistent way, and if you respected naming conventions. Half your variables start with a lowercase letter, and the other half with an uppercase letter. How do you remember which one uses which convention? Why not use the same convention always?

Comment: @JBNizet I will improve this in better format, Thanks . I do remember.

Answer (score 0):

You have no attribute named `good` in your scope. So `{{ good }}` will always be empty.

The scope attribute is named `Info`. So you want `{{ Info }}`.

Comment: I did it , still the data is not displaying

Comment: Is the second controller already created, and its view displayed in the page, when you click on the link? Because if it isn't, nothing is listening yet for the event when the first controller emits it. Use your debugger, add console.log() in the code, and, if you're still stuck, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Yes second controller is already created , and no , its view displayed on other page .. which is linked with 2nd controller.

Comment: If the controller is the controller of another route, that is not displayed yet, then the controller is not created yet. it will only be when the route is activated, i.e. after the first controller emits the event.

Comment: Even the route is activated for each and every HTML page with respected to their controllers , I had checked each and every file . All are working good.